# How to pass ampersand (&) to AngularJS resource parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, urlencode, angularjs-resource

I have an angular resource declared as follows

```
angular.module('xpto', ['ngResource'])
.factory('XPTO', function ($resource, $location) {
    var XPTO = $resource($location.protocol() + '://' + $location.host() +
    ':port' + '/myservice.svc/gerencia?sigla=:sigla',
        {
            port: ':' + $location.port()
        }
    );
    return XPTO;
})
```

and I would like to call the service passaing a parameter that contains an ampersand (&), something like:

```
XPTO.query({ sigla: 'abc&d' }, function (gerencias) {
$scope.gerenciasBuscadas = gerencias;
});
```

However, AngularJS does not encode the & properly. It sends "sigla=abc&d" instead of "sigla=abc%26d" , causing my server to see the query string parameter value for "sigla" as being just "abc", instead of "abc&d".

Looking into angular-resource-1.0.7.js, I saw the following:

```
/**
 * We need our custom method because encodeURIComponent is too aggressive and doesn't follow
 * http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt with regards to the character set (pchar) allowed in path
 * segments:
 *    segment       = *pchar
 *    pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
 *    pct-encoded   = "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG
 *    unreserved    = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
 *    sub-delims    = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
 *                     / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
 */
function encodeUriSegment(val) {
  return encodeUriQuery(val, true).
    replace(/%26/gi, '&').
    replace(/%3D/gi, '=').
    replace(/%2B/gi, '+');
}
```

So, it will encode '&' and decode it back before it sends the request to the server. Is there any point where I could customize the url right before it is sent to the server? Changing encodeUriSegment is an option, but it might break other stuff inside Angular. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/12201) in AngularJS.

I posted a pull request for fixing this. You can help me getting it merged commenting on the pull request itself [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/12201).